# swagger does not display calls which start with a path parameter

Tags: .net, servicestack, swagger

I encountered that when having a route to a path with a path parameter at the beginning, this method is not been display when accessing swagger via `swagger-ui`.

Example:

```
[Route("/{Version}/userdata", "GET")]
public class UserData
{
 //...
}
```

I am also using paths like `/v1/getSomeData` and `/v2/getSomeOtherData` which are correctly displayed in the `swagger-ui`. But there should also be some methods which can have different versions (v1/v2) which I access via the path variable at the beginning of the path.

Is that possible with swagger? Of course I also need to display 2 methods for the the `/{Version}/userdata` since each version has a different response etc.

Comment: It should be possible. Please post your swagger file.

Comment: sorry, which swagger file do you mean?

Comment: swagger is an endpoint specification format which uses json or yaml. it is therefore possible to define your endpoint using the swagger file specification. See my answer

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea where to find the swagger file. I used this package https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API which apparently implements swagger 1.2. There is no json or yaml file in the project or in the builded app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger 2.0 [specification](http://swagger.io/specification/) definition for your endpoint will be something like the below:

```
{
    "paths":{
        "/{Version}/userdata":{
            "get":{
                "produces":[
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json"
                ],
                "parameters":[
                    {
                        "name":"Version",
                        "in":"path",
                        "required":true,
                        "type":"string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses":{
                    "200":{
                        "description":"OK"
                    },
                    etc...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So there's nothing intrinsically impossible about defining the endpoint `/{Version}/userdata` using the swagger specification.

However, the Service Stack swagger generation [tooling](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api) only supports the swagger [1.2 spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md). According to @mythz, who is the technical lead on Service Stack, what you want to do is unsupported using the existing tooling.

If this is the case, and you definitely require a swagger definition for your service, then you can do one of:

1. change your endpoint route to something which the tooling does support
2. create your swagger definition manually
3. change your tooling

In your situation, I think the best thing to do would be to change your endpoint route so that the existing tooling can generate the definition. This means removing the path parameter.

If you can't do this then I would create a swagger 2.0 definition manually. If you need help with this please let me know.

Comment: What is the [Swagger 1.2 spec path](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#511-object-example) field suppose to generate?

Comment: @mythz - not sure what you mean.

Comment: Swagger 1.2 needs to generate a [resource listing](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#51-resource-listing) what should the `path` field contain here?

Comment: @mythz I'm confused. I'm familiar with version 2.0 of swagger, as defined here http://swagger.io/specification/ or https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md. This defines a paths parameter https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#pathsObject

Comment: @mythz - also I'm unfamiliar with the verb "generate" when applied to swagger. Swagger is an api specification format, it doesn't generate anything does it?

Comment: Don't get hung up on it, Swagger specs are often generated as-is the case with ServiceStack which this question is about

Comment: ok I am confused. I am not sure what you mean with "tooling" and "service" in this context. I am using https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API which should generate the swagger-ui which should contain my REST-methods from my c# code. So I am not sure what "tooling" I could change there.

Comment: @zlZimon - in this context, "service" refers to your service operation, which is a HTTP GET against a resource called UserData. "Tooling" refers to the tool you are using to generate the swagger, in your case the swagger API tool provided by service stack. The swagger definition produced in this manner is compliant with swagger 1.2 specification, which does not support your requirement. However, my answer is compliant with swagger 2.0 spec, which does support your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger UI groups and displays its routes under the **root /path** which needs to be a literal path.

Comment: yes, I know. The one with the literal path like `/v1/somerequest` are perfectly grouped. Any work around how I get the one with a parameter to be displayed without breaking anything?